# How can I avoid duplicate triangles in the opposite direction when rendering objects in a 3D graphics game?

Tags: javascript, 3d, logic, game-engine, p5.js

I am trying to build my own 3d graphics game using p5.js, but I am experiencing some problems when it comes to actually rendering the objects. For example, it stops working when you are inside of the polygon and when you look in the other direction it shows a duplicate version but flipped. But I am not entirely sure why this is happening.

I realise this is probably with the way I am rendering the triangle onto screen or when projecting the points onto the camera plane, but when I have tried to abs the z coord but it does not fix the problem. This is how I am displaying the triangle after the plane has been rotated.

```
triangle((newVertex[0].x*player.getFOV()/newVertex[0].z)*(windowWidth)+windowWidth/2,(newVertex[0].y*player.getFOV()/newVertex[0].z)*(windowWidth/(windowHeight/windowWidth))+windowHeight/2,(newVertex[1].x*player.getFOV()/newVertex[1].z)*(windowWidth)+windowWidth/2,(newVertex[1].y*player.getFOV()/newVertex[1].z)*(windowWidth/(windowHeight/windowWidth))+windowHeight/2,(newVertex[2].x*player.getFOV()/newVertex[2].z)*(windowWidth)+windowWidth/2,(newVertex[2].y*player.getFOV()/newVertex[2].z)*(windowWidth/(windowHeight/windowWidth))+windowHeight/2)
```

*new vertex is the vertices after it has been transformed by the camera

*FOV is the camera plane distance from origin r.n = d or (d)

```
calculateVertexInCamera(value) {
    let newValue = createVector(value.x, value.y, value.z);
  newValue = newValue.sub(player.getPos());
    
    newValue = this.matrix3DApply(newValue.x,newValue.y,newValue.z,
                          cos(-player.getRotation().x), 0, sin(-player.getRotation().x),
                            0,1,0,
                           -sin(-player.getRotation().x),0,cos(-player.getRotation().x));
    newValue = this.matrix3DApply(newValue.x,newValue.y,newValue.z,
                          1,0,0,
                          0,cos(-player.getRotation().y),-sin(-player.getRotation().y),
                          0,sin(-player.getRotation().y),cos(-player.getRotation().y));
    
    return newValue;
  }
```

If anyone could show me what I could do to fix this problem or any other issue with my code that could fix this would be greatly appreciated!

full code: https://editor.p5js.org/JamesB_/sketches/20dIVhRfh